# Trying to get the simplest way of making this number table constructor to work... in Lua

Tags: lua, number-formatting, lua-table

I wanted to find out the simplest way (so that, ideally, everything could be wrote in the same line) for construct a table of superscript numbers that I can easily use afterwards up to at least 99, but it's not giving to me the expected results doing it e. g. like this:

```html
<script src="//github.com/fengari-lua/fengari-web/releases/download/v0.1.4/fengari-web.js"></script>
<script type="application/lua">

local numbers = {[0] = "⁰", "¹", "²", "³", "⁴", "⁵", "⁶", "⁷", "⁸", "⁹"}
for i = #numbers + 1, 999 do
    numbers[i] = numbers[math.floor(i/10)] .. numbers[i%10]
end
print(table.concat(numbers, " ")) --print(numbers:concat(" "))

</script>
```

I'm sure I'm not seeing something obvious but, at the moment I write this, for me it should be simply continuing the sequence instead of just start repeating 21...

And well, since this should have been a quick secondary task and turns out it's taking more time than it could deserve, I've decided to came here looking for the reason is not working or, even better, maybe find a preferable approach (for example to make it work no matter the figure length, since this only would work for 2 figure numbers), so thanks for any inputs!

P.S. BTW, any reason for this: `print(numbers:concat())` not working? I'd swear I've seen this way of deal with tables as well, but not getting it work here is making me doubt...

**EDIT¹:** Getting at least the code to work thanks to @user253751 inputs.
**EDIT²:** And improving it too by using instead `math.floor(i/10)` and `i%10` as suggested.

Comment: # of a string means the number of characters in the string, not what you think it means.

Comment: @user253751 Oh, wait... I think I knew what it does, but looking now to the code again I sincerely don't really know why I used # there... Anyway, the question now is, why this instead doesn't work either? `numbers[i] = numbers[tonumber(tostring(i):sub(1))] .. numbers[tonumber(tostring(i):sub(-1))]` 

Comment: tostring(10):sub(1) is "10" and tostring(10):sub(-1) is "0"

Comment: @user253751 OMG, of course it had to be `tostring(i):sub(1, 1)`, ‍♂️ thanks for pointing it out...

Comment: you could also use math.floor(i/10) and i%10

Comment: @user253751 GREAT! It seems to work now no matter the figure as can be seen and in a much more simple (and elegant ), way... Thanks so much!

Comment: @user253751 BTW, if you feel like adding your last comment solution as an answer I'll mark it as the one solving the issue without any doubt, since I don't think after such addition the code could be simplified much more... Or, if not, maybe I could do it, but I wanted to make you know before just in case... In any case, many thanks again!